# Laravel's TestCase method seeJson() only looks for array

Tags: php, json, unit-testing, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 Testsuite.

Now, I test my json api with the method seeJson(). This method expects an array, such as:

```
->seeJson(['created' => 1]);
```

But my json api always returns a *json object* or an *array with json objects* with, in this case:

```
Response::json(['created' => 1], 200);
```

In the case above, my json api returns:

```
{created: 1}
```

But seeJson() looks for the given array exactly:

```
[created: 1]
```

I never get my tests pass with a match. How can I match?

Answer (score 3):

I received a similar error.

> Unable to find JSON fragment ["created":1] within [{"created":"1"}......]

Looking at the source code, that error is written as:

```
"Unable to find JSON fragment [{$expected}] within [{$actual}]."
```

So the `[` `]` are not being included in the search

```
Response::json(['created' => 1], 200);
```

results in:
    `{"created":1}`

When I dump out the response content within the `seeJson()` method, all values are in quotes. Try changing your test to:

```
->seeJson(['created' => '1']);
```

Answer (score 3):

`seeJson` make strict comparisons, so:

```
'created' => 1 (Interpreted as integer)
```

Will fail because the JSON returned by your API is actually

```
"created":"1" (interpreted as string)
```